# Does this ODE has an explicit solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE $\frac{y'(x)}{y'(x)^2+1}+x y(x)=0$.
Mathematica shows that it seems this ODE cannot be solved explicitly. I'm quite curious it can be explicitly solved or not.

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: $y(x) = 0, \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ are three solutions. Not sure whether there are other solutions or not.

Comment: Thank! Indeed, they are three solutions. May I know how you got it?

Comment: parameterize the curve by arc-length, the ODE becomes $\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dy}{ds} + xy = 0$. I notice $\frac{dx}{ds} = -y, \frac{dy}{ds} = x$ is a solution of this ODE. Together with $|\frac{dx}{ds}|^2 + |\frac{dy}{ds}|^2 = 1$, I get two of the three solutions.

Comment: I see. It is a very good observation!

Comment: So now a natural question arises. How to show they are the only three solutions, or there exists another solution?

Comment: If you make a stream plot of the ODE, it is clear there are other solutions. The problem is how to obtain explicit expressions for these solutions.

Comment: I found we have similar 2-D result: $u(x,y)=\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}$ solves $\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2+1}+(x,y)\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}=(0,0)$. Obviously, we can extend to n-D case.

Comment: I'm also curious how to find explicit expressions of other solutions.